# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, datetime, type-conversion

I'm trying to store a `datetime` into a SQL database. I use `datetime2(0)` variable for that purpose.

But i always get this exception :

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string

Here's my code that generates the error :

```
protected void InsertDB(string title, string desc, string cat, string path)
{
    string now = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy h:mm:ss tt");
    title = title.Length == 0 ? "Untitled" : title;
    cat = cat.Length == 0 ? "Uncategorized" : cat;
    string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
        try
        {                    
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO gallery (img_title, img_desc, img_cat, img_date, img_path)
                                            VALUES (@title, @desc, @cat, @date, @path)", con);
            con.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", title.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desc", desc.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cat", cat.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", now.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@path", path.Trim());
            int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (result == 1)
            {
                msg_lbl.Visible = true;
                msg_lbl.Text = "New Image is uploaded.";
                title_txt.Text = "";
                desc_txt.Text = "";
                cat_txt.Text = "";                        
            }
            else
            {
                msg_lbl.Visible = true;
                msg_lbl.Text = "Error occured.";
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            msg_lbl.Visible = true;
            msg_lbl.Text = ex.Message; //I get this exception here
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            msg_lbl.Visible = true;
            msg_lbl.Text = ex.Message;
        }

    }
```

Comment: If you get rid of your now local variable and simply use DateTime.Now for your parameter, it should work. **We** have the concept of what format a date has. Internally, .net and SQL Server store it how they want and worry about presentation issues when needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error must be when passing the variable "now" in the sql query. If the column `Img_date` is a datetime field then you must pass the value as a a datetime not as a string. Try assigning the value `Datetime.Now` to the parameter `@date` :

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateTime.Now);
```

Answer (score 1):

When using `DateTime2` columns, you need to specifically set the parameter type - it defaults to `DateTime` with `AddWithValue`.

Try this:

```
SqlParameter parm = cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime2);
parm.Value = DateTime.Now;
```

According to MSDN:

> The @date parameter could map to a date, datetime, or datetime2 data
>   type on the server. When working with the new datetime data types, you
>   must explicitly set the parameter's SqlDbType property to the data
>   type of the instance. Using Variant or implicitly supplying parameter
>   values can cause problems with backward compatibility with the
>   datetime and smalldatetime data types.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675168.aspx

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error because tsql won't accept the 'tt' format specifier.